Adjusting `Display_errors` in PHP.ini automatically adds deprecated directive `track_errors` resulting in PHP breaking
Modifying  display_errors from Off to On in the PHP.ini config file will result in the deprecated track_errors directive being inserted automatically upon file save. This then results in the following error being reported in the PHP error file when any PHP script is run:
PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'track_errors' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0.
PHP version is 8.3.6 and running on windows server.
Any ideas on how to be able to output PHP errors without breaking PHP entirely?

"will result in the deprecated track_errors directive being inserted automatically upon file save" - I suppose you must be talking about some sort of program or UI you are using to change the PHP settings?

@CBroe that program is notepad. IIS may be doing something else if it detects the setting is set to On. but i dont know

My guess is that track_errors is always set. But when errors are not displayed on screen it's easy to miss them, esp. if you don't set a custom error_log directive and messages end up in some unexpected location like web server logs or Windows event logs. There's actually little magic involved: run <?php phpinfo(); to figure out where the INI file is and edit it to remove the offending directive.
